# Angular HttpClient.get vs Postman

Tags: angular

I have an API that returns ~50kb of data via an HTTP GET. I noticed then when hitting the API with postman response time is ~800 ms, however when using the same API with Angular httpClient chrome dev tools shows it takes ~8 seconds. Majority of that time is in "Content Download".

My service method performs:

`return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.baseUrl + "endpoint", { params });`

Is there something i'm missing with how httpClient works, I've never noticed such difference in performance before.

I'm using Angular 5.2.5

Comment: i never seen this issue before have you try to clear your chrome history?

Comment: did you fin any solution ?

Comment: Yes did you found what was the reason